# How can a tooltip in D3 fetch data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

We have some data

```
University,Total,Females,Males,Year,Type
PortSaid,13817,6679,7138,2012,Public
PortSaid,14790,7527,7263,2013,Public
PortSaid,17295,8509,8786,2010,Public
6OctoberUniversity,12507,4297,8210,2012,Private
6OctoberUniversity,14608,5360,9248,2013,Private
```

I try to create piechart like this [Block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/32bd93b1cc0fbccc9bf9) with a dynamic tooltip attached. 
I create a HTML element manually

```
        <p>
            <strong>University is </strong>
            <span id="UniversityName"></span>
        </p>
        <p><span id="NumberStudents"></span> Students</p>
```

And the code for creating the arcs and the tooltips

```
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append("path")
            .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .on("mouseover", arcTween(outerRadius, 0))
            .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150))
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                var xPosition = 100;
                var yPosition = 100;
                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .data(pie(data))
                      .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                      .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                      .select("#NumberStudents")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.value })
                      .select("#UniversityName")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.value });
                    //Show the tooltip
                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
                })
            .on("mouseout", function() {

                //Hide the tooltip
                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);          
           })
```

**The Question**:
The Tooltip always returns the first value of the Total column, i.e. 13817. How can it dynamically display the correct value according to the mouseovered arc?

---

EDIT: Added second data point #UniversityName in code snippet & in HTML tooltip template.

**Question 2**
As @minikomi points out, correct data binding would result in the value associated with each arc being fetched correctly. However, it seems that a each arc has a single value attached to it, correctly the one labeled **Total**. 
Yet, where does this leave the rest of the data per row, as in **Female, Male** or **Year**? How can I bind them to the tooltip as well?

Comment: That would be simply `d3.select("#tooltip").text(d.value);`, no?

Comment: In regards to your edit: check my comment, my edit to the answer and the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#_pie). The docs are very comprehensive so if you're trying to learn from blocks, it's a good idea to read each line and check what it's doing with the docs in another tab.

Comment: @minikomi I have trouble relating the docs to the data model of javascript, it gets quite confusing. Using the console to guess/asses the data any given point is almost useless (Though recommended in the docs!) Thanks for the help, I'll give them a fresh look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be worth reviewing the ideas behind d3 & [data binding](https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements) to the dom.

Here:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
            var xPosition = 100;
            var yPosition = 100;
            d3.select("#tooltip")
                .data(pie(data)) // re-bind tooltip with entire data set
                  .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                  .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                  .select("#NumberStudents")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.value });
                //Show the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
            })
```

The original `data` is an array. When you use `.data`, `.enter` and `.each`, not only is a segment of the pie chart created, but each segment also has a single data point bound to it.

So, when you tell the segment to react to a mouseover event, the `d` argument of the callback function will be set by d3 to the bound data point for that segment.

In contrast, in your code above, after selecting the #tooltip element, there's a call to `.data(pie(data))` - which will bind the *entire data set* to the tooltip each time you mouseover - and is the cause of the unexpected behavior you observe.

Instead, use the single data item (d within the function here) and its value to set the text of the tooltip:

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            // d = the single data point used 
            //     to create the segment here
            var xPosition = 100;
            var yPosition = 100;
            d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                .select("#NumberStudents")
                  .text(d.value);

            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
            })
```

To access the other values (separate from the one used to create the pie slices), check the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#_pie) for pie layout. The original datum will be in the .data attribute of d. So, for example, assuming your tooltip has a `#SchoolType` `<span>` then you can set the text from the `Type` attribute like:

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {

            var xPosition = 100;
            var yPosition = 100;
            d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                .select("#NumberStudents")
                  .text(d.value)

            //d.data will hold the original data map
            d3.select("#tooltip #SchoolType").text(d.data["Type"]);

            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
            })
```

Comment: That works, but I still don't understand fully.
It seems that .data(pie(data)) creates an array of arcs, with each having the Total value attached. However, the rest of the data associated with the data, i.e. Females, Males, Year etc. (Which would require an object) are missing. I cannot reference them for a complete Tooltip. 

Question: How can I reference a second data point per row of cvs data? Is that even possible?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#_pie) for pie layout. The original datum will be in the `.data` attribute of d.

So, you can say d.data["Females"] and get the females value, for example.